# object of another class in constructor

Tags: c++, object

I have a class Project. A project itself has different tasks. So I made a for loop in the constructor of the Project to add the different objects of 'Task'.

My code is as follows:

in Project.cpp :

```
Project::Project(int readnumber)
{
//constructor
int Projectnumber= 1; // ????
int Projectduration = 0;
int Numbertasks = 0;

ReadRanGenData(readnumber);
Numbertasks = numberAct;
vector<Task> Tasks(Numbertasks);
for (int i = 0; i < numberAct; i++)
{
    Tasks[i].SetTaskNumber(i + 1);
    cout << "in sub: " << Tasks[i].GetTaskNumber();

}

}
```

In this constructor I made a vector of tasks. These tasks have their own attributes (such as task number etc). 
In task.cpp I have methods to set the variables (SetTaskNumber ).

I also have methods to call the data of my Project:

```
vector<Task> Project::GetTasks()
{

cout << "test" <<  Tasks[0].GetTaskNumber();
return Tasks;
}
```

But when I tried to test out whether I could access the tasknumber I got the error: vector subscript out of range.
I then tried to access the tasknumber directly in the constructor ( cout << "in sub: " << Tasks[i].GetTaskNumber(); ) and no errors appeared, I got the correct result.
How can I fix this?

And a second question : In the constructor I wrote int Projectnumber = 1; But ideally the projectnumber always goes up with 1 when I create a new object. I wanted to do that with int Projectnumber = ++1; but I get an error when I try that.

Comment: You declare a local variable `Tasks` in your constructor. If you have a member variable in your class, you are working with the local variable in the constructor and the member variable in the function.

Comment: Regarding second question (create two separate questions if they are unrelated like here): You need to use a static member to hold the last `Projectnumber` assigned. `++1` makes no sense.

Comment: Show us your header file too.  Try and create a [mcve]